# VB.NET- Introducir valores en un arreglo

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, array, vb.net

Estoy haciendo un arreglo unidimensional de tamaño N (este valor lo ingresa el usuario en en un textbox) en Visual Basic.net. Ahora quiero que ingresar los números al arreglo pero no encuentro en ningún lado cómo hacerlo a partir de un textbox o que aparezca una ventana y vaya pidiendo los números de acuerdo al tamaño que se le asignó al arreglo.

¿Alguien me puede dar un ejemplo de como ingresar los valores y que se almacenen para despues hacer una operación con ellos?

Esto es lo único que encontré en internet sobre el tema, lo apliqué a lo que necesito pero no funciona:

```
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
    Button2.Click
    Dim N As Integer
    Dim V(N)
    Dim i As Integer

    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese los valores para V")
    For i = 0 To V.Length
        V(i) = Console.ReadLine
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hola. Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia. visita [ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) si necesitas mas ayuda sobre como preguntar o que tipo de preguntas son validas en el sitio. Un arreglo no es diferente a una variable. por favor agrega lo que probaste y el codigo que llevas hasta ahora.

Comment: Para que podamos ayudarte con tu problema deberás compartir el fragmento de código con lo que hayas intentado hasta ahora.

Comment: Hola ya agregué lo que llevo del código, como lo dije es casi imposible encontrar información sobre el tema incluso en inglés, parece que esto de introducir valores a un arreglo no se puede hacer porque no encuentro información sobre el tema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La creación del `Array` sería de la siguiente manera:

```vb
Dim tamanio As Integer = 20
Dim array(tamanio) As String
```

Para insertar valores en el `Array` simplemente usa:

```
array(posicion) = valor
```

***Ejemplo:***

```
array(3) = 45
```

Puedes ayudarte de un `InputBox` para ir pidiendo los distintos valores del `array` según el tamaño del mismo:

```
For cont As Integer = 0 To tamanio - 1
    array(cont) = InputBox("Introduce valor", "Introduce valor para Array", "")
Next
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para mostrar el resultado en un diálogo con todos los elementos del `array` puedes poner:

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Join(".", array))
```

Comment: Gracias lo voy a intentar!!!

Comment: Lo acabo de implementar, ingrese un valor de 4 para N pero funcionó hasta el segundo elemento del arreglo después arroja un mensaje de error que Índice fuera de los límites de la matriz.https://ibb.co/m2iZRQ :(

Comment: fijate en lo que compartiste.... definiste N, luego definiste el arreglo de tamaño N, y despues pediste N.. esta mal el orden en que haces las cosas.. deberias definir el arreglo una vez que sepas el valor de N

Comment: Oh, ok muchas gracias voy a corregir.

Comment: Funcionó, ¡¡¡¡¡muchas gracias!!!!!

Comment: @IraidaMercedes Considera marcar la respuesta como correcta si te ha funcionado :)